# How to show an alert to the user inside a completion block in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, background, uialertcontroller

I have an app that makes an API call to a web server. I finally got the API call to work correctly and can now parse the JSON data the server returns, but I am stuck with trying to show an alert to the user if the request fails. For example, my server can return {"success": false, "error": "You didn't ask nicely"} Obviously that error is not real, but a representation of what can be returned. I can only check the error inside the completion block of the URLSession.shared.dataTask, but if I try to show an alert from inside that I get the error that I cannot perform any operation from a background thread on the UI.

The code is rather simple right now...

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) { (data, response, error) in 
    if let error = error {
        completion(.failure(error))
        return
    }
    //continue on with processing the response...
    completion(.success(fullResponse))
}.resume()
```

Then in my calling code I have...

```
connector.connect(pin) { (result) in
    switch(result) {
    case .success(let response):
        if let response = response {
            if response.success {
                //do things
            } else {
                self.alert(title: "Error while connecting", message: response.error)
            }
         }
    case .failure(let error):
        self.alert(title: "Unable to connect", message: error)
  }
}
```

That is causing the error that I can't do anything on the ui thread from a background thread. If that is the case, how do I let the user know that the API call failed? I have to be able to notify the user. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` as callback of `URLSession.shared.dataTask`  occurs in a background thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.alert(title: "Error while connecting", message: response.error)
}
```

Same also for

```
self.alert(title: "Unable to connect", message: error)
```

but it's better to wrap all code inside `alert` function inside the main queue to be a single place

Comment: beautiful! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach you can use, instead of calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` on `connector.connect(pin)`'s callback you could also do it before you call the `completion` block on your `dataTask` like this.

```swift
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: self.request) { (data, response, error) in 
    if let error = error {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
        return
    }
    //continue on with processing the response...
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(.success(fullResponse))
    }
}.resume()
```

By doing this your code inside `connector.connect(pin)` won't be placed in a pyramid of doom, and everything in the completion block is running on the main thread.

```swift
connector.connect(pin) { result in
    // everything in here is on the main thread now
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. I hadn't thought about it that way. Thank you sir!

Comment: @NeglectedSanity If you liked it you can **upvote** my answer.